.NET Integration Test Singleton Service instantiated twice
I am working on a .NET SQL Server based application for which I need to write Integration tests.
I am using CustomWebApplicationFactory to overide DbContextFactory to use an in-memory SQLite DB in test -
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> 
: WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        // Remove the app's ApplicationDbContext registration.
        removeService(services, typeof(DbContextOptions<PimsDbContext>));
        removeService(services, typeof(IDbContextFactory<PimsDbContext>));

        // Use in-memory SQLite database for testing.
        // Create single connection for all DbContext instances, as a new SQLite in-memory database is created for each connection.
        services.AddSingleton<DbConnection>(container =>
        {
            var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine($"Connection address dbcontextfactory: {connection.GetHashCode()}");
            return connection;
        });

        // Override DB context in Program.cs with SQLite in-memory database
        services.AddDbContextFactory<PimsDbContext>((container, options) =>
        {
            var connection = container.GetRequiredService<DbConnection>();
            options.UseSqlite(connection);
        }, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
        // Build the service provider.
        var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var dbContextFactory = sp.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<PimsDbContext>>();
        var db = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

        // Ensure the database is created.
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();

        SeedData(db);
    });
}

But when I run the test, I observed that application is using a different instance of DbContextFactory than the one injected in ConfigureServices, due to which the seeded data is not present in that Dbcontext while running the test.
Test -
public class ControllerIntegrationTest
{
    private CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;
    private HttpClient _client;
    
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>();
        _client = _factory.CreateClient();
    }

    //... Test methods calling controller endpoint

}

Any idea why application is not using the same singleton DbContextFactory?

Found the issue.
Since I was calling services.BuildServiceProvider() in ConfigureWebHost, serviceProvider was getting instantiated twice, once in ConfigureWebHost, then the web application will build it when initializing the app. This led to multiple instances of DbContextFactory.
Solution: Move seeding data call to test code by retrieving ServiceProvider from _factory.Services.GetRequiredService<>() and not instantiate serviceProvider in ConfigureWebHost.
